# Usage statistics in Android

Tags: dialer-codes, intents

Is there any intent or method to get the values which show in the usage statistics? We can get that manually by dialing `*#*#4636#*#*`.

Comment: If you're trying to launch an intent for this in code then you'll want to ask on [so]; development questions are outside the scope of this site. If not, then you may want to explain in more detail what it is that you're trying to do exactly, and why the dialer code is not sufficient. That will help people give you the most relevant answers possible.

Comment: If you simply want to add a shortcut to your homescreen to access that menu, some launchers offer to do so for "activities". That menu has declared such an activity publically, so that would be possible (and on-topic here ;).

Comment: How to add android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS to the application?

Comment: That permission cannot be granted to any third-party app. Visit this for more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html Also, since this is a programming question I VTC it.